# List of WSS endpoints for parachains (OR Is there a way to parse typescript code into JSON or other python readable object?)

Tags: polkadot-js, parachain, wss

I would like to programmatically get a list of all the WSS urls for parachains.  I don't know if this is available anywhere, but I have not seen it.  [This source code](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/master/packages/apps-config/src/endpoints/productionRelayPolkadot.ts) has what I want, but it is in the form of a TypeScript function.  I tried to paste the code into a JSON object, but I don't think my JSON skills are good enough to get it to work, besides that would require manual updating.  Anyone have a better, or more automated idea?

Answer (score 2):

There's a new collaboration project called the polkadot_network_directory.
I'm hoping that this may solve this:

https://paritytech.github.io/polkadot_network_directory/registry.json

PRs welcome if the data you need isn't there. (I'm hoping that npm and crate packages might be built off the back of this.)